# install git-recover to recover files from hard reset

Tags: git

I staged some changed and then did a hard reset on a repository, before doing the first commit. As a result, I lost many files. I'd like to recover those files.

I was told that by installing git-recover I could recover them. However, I'm having problems installing it. According to [this](https://edwardthomson.com/blog/introducing_git_recover.html), I should download the shell script and then add the file to the PATH variable. I did so, but I still get "'recover' is not a git command".

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it is a shell script, so it needs to be executed in a bash session (on Windows, a `git bash` session)

Second, make sure the script is executable: `chmod 755 git-recover`. That will ensure it is working within your `PATH`.